# How to create a sequence of functions defined recursively?

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I'm trying to create a Table of functions where each new element is defined recursively via indefinite integration of the previous one. I've tried doing:

```
RecurrenceTable[{f[n + 1] == Integrate[f[n], x], f[0] == x}, f, {n,10}]
```

However I get the following output:

```
{x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7, x^8, x^9, x^10, x^11}
```

I've also tried doing several variations of this like:

```
RecurrenceTable[{f[n + 1, x] == Integrate[f[n, x], x], f[0, x] := x}, f, {n, 10}]
```

But it throws up an error message.
I'm new to Mathematica, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the first output you get? What were you expecting instead? And what would you like to obtain?

Comment: @MarcoB I was expecting x, x^2/2, x^3/6, etc.

Comment: Use ``NestList`` instead: ``NestList[Integrate[#, x] &, x, 10]``.

Comment: "each new element is defined recursively via indefinite integration of the previous one" - have you already seen [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html)?

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As suggested by Domen, use [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

```
seq = NestList[Integrate[#, x] &, x, 6]

(* {x, x^2/2, x^3/6, x^4/24, x^5/120, x^6/720, x^7/5040} *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, using [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html), delay the integration

```
seq = RecurrenceTable[{f[n + 1] == g[f[n], x], f[0] == x}, f, {n, 6}] /. 
  g -> Integrate

(* {x, x^2/2, x^3/6, x^4/24, x^5/120, x^6/720, x^7/5040} *)
```

Then use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize the result

```
f[n_, x_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // FunctionExpand

(* x^n/Gamma[1 + n] *)
```

Comment: The formula in the MathWorld link I gave above quickly generates the required expression: `Assuming[x > 0 && n > 0, Integrate[t (x - t)^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!, {t, 0, x}]]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Trace, you can see what's happening. We evaluate the Integrate before solving the recurrence. So, the recurrence that actually gets used is this:

```
f[1 + n] == x f[n]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
f[n_, x_]:= f[n, x]= If[n==0, 1, Integrate[f[n-1, t], {t, 0, x}]];
Table[f[n, x], {n, 10}]
```

which gives the result:

```
{x, x^2/2, x^3/6, x^4/24, x^5/120, x^6/720, x^7/5040, x^8/40320, x^9/362880, x^10/3628800}
```